# I can't log in because I delete `/etc/passwd`. How can I recover my files?

Tags: hard-drive, files

I can't log in to Ubuntu because by accident I deleted the passwd files. I have many important files on my hard disk of which I have no backup. How can I recover them?

Comment: What files are you trying to recover and what does it have to do with booting? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: i want to retrieve that imp files stored in hard disk...so i used usb to boot the pc ..my question is if i boot whether hard disk files will be deleted

Comment: Still not understandable. Please [edit] and explain what's wrong.

Comment: Important files should always have at least one backup (on a different drive, cloud, etc), or else they can't really be that important

Answer (score 0):

If you boot from a live USB you are doing the correct thing. Your hard drive will be accessible and the live USB will not delete any data in the hard drive.

Use a second USB (storage USB) to transfer the data from the hard drive to the storage USB.